How to use cherry-pick with options -x and -s in Webstorm?
Webstorm provides cherry-pick in right click menu, but I can't use -x or -s options with it
I only can use command line to add -x and -s instead of right click menu, or set an alias for git cherry-pick -x -s. Thx for help

Webstorm has a builtin terminal, so you can use the options there :)
